# The opposite feeling of oily when it comes to scalp

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, phrase-requests

I came across this question when I want to describe the feeling after using a shampoo.

> The scalp usually feels oily or **?????** after using a shampoo

When we feel oily it seems the shampoo is mainly nourished effect. On the other hand, some shampoos are mainly for cleaning your scalp, you will feel very dry. Does this sense of dryness have a better expression?

Comment: "Dry" is the name for one of the 'hair conditions' that shampoos target.

Comment: This seems to me more a medical question, which may be better answered on the "health" site.

Comment: feels greasy or ["stripped of its natural oils"](https://www.google.com/search?ei=mI9YWoDCOcv-UrPEpZAE&q=stripped+of+%22its+natural+oils%22&oq=stripped+of+%22its+natural+oils%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...15024.17113.0.17447.2.2.0.0.0.0.149.296.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.kucNt-YOJi0)

Comment: You don't have a squeaky clean scalp, it's **squeaky clean hair**. You test hair for cleanliness by rubbing a wet lock of hair between your thumb and forefinger. If it squeaks, it means all the grease and dirt has been removed, like after washing the plates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Squeaky-clean*, perhaps?

> **squeaky-clean** adjective [informal]
>
> completely clean:
>
> - I love the squeaky-clean feel of my hair after I've washed it.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/squeaky-clean)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick scan for synonyms of dryness, I think

> [desiccated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desiccate)

**preserved by drying**

fits your context best, conveying the sensation of a medicine (in this case, a shampoo) being beneficial to one's health.